# Android: how to avoid multiple measure calls

Tags: android, performance, layout

I've got a `DialogFragment` with a medium complexity layout (about 50 views, see it's structure below).

After certain computations I have to update up to 10 fields in the same method.
The problem is that update leads to tangible UI delay (about 0.5s on my test phone).

I've profiled my dialog:
1) My calculations and my update code take <5ms to run
2) About 95% of CPU time take measure-related methods (like `onMeasure()`, `measureHierarchy()`, `measureChildWithMargins()` etc) 
I've never encountered this behavior before.

**Question**
**1)** Does Android re-measures all the layout after every view update (even if they are done one after another)?
**2)** Is there a way to force measure-only-after-all-values-updated (like stopping measure before setting values and resuming just after)?
**3)** Where else should I look for problems?

Thanks a lot!

Layout structure:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <CheckBox />
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            <CheckBox />
            <RelativeLayout>
                <RadioButton />
                <Spinner />
                <TextView />
                <RadioButton />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout>
                <RadioButton />
                <Spinner />
                <RadioButton />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <RadioButton />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <RadioButton />
                <Spinner />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <RadioButton />
                <TextView />
                <TextView />
                <LinearLayout>
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                    <TextView />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <View />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS is taking care about UI refresh. So once you set something via .set the UI is updated. There could be some optimizations, but I am not aware of them.

There are some options to save CPU time.

1. You could build your views on background thread and then execute just root_view.addView(child_view), where root_view is some empty view generated on main thread and child is view which contains entire view hierarchy. If you use this approach measure, layout and other slow methods won't be executed each time when you call .set. This approach is working well in most cases.
2. If there is some reason why you could not make views on background thread you could try to override measure(), layout(), draw() methods for these views. There should be some boolean flag which will indicate if you are going to make more updates to UI or this one will be the last one. So if the flag indicates that there will be more updates you can "return" from above three functions without calculating anything at all, otherwise just call super.measure(), super.draw(), super.layout().

   ```
   protected void measure(...) {
       if (flag)
           return;
       super.measure();
   }
   ```

In my projects I'm using using 1st approach. The second one is.... if there is nothing else you could do and I definitely do not recommend it.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks! The first method is a good hack! Still it looks strange that Android doesn't provide any means to control measure behavior...